# A misunderstanding about the number of points on an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Consider the multivariate polynomial $Q(x,y) = y^2 - f(x)$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ has $m$ distinct roots in $\mathbb{F}_q$. In his book "*Equations over Finite Fields*", Schmidt claims that if $Q$ is absolutely irreducible then $N$, the number of points on the algebraic variety specified by $Q$, satisfies
$$|N - q| \leq (m-1) \sqrt{q}.$$
Now, what if $f(x)$ itself is irreducible? In that case we have $m=0$ and the above inequality would not make sense.

Comment: $m$ is the degree of $f$, and the assumption is that $f$ has $m$ distinct roots in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @quasi If it is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$ then it makes sense. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @quasi that looks like an answer to me - please consider recording it as such below.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, $m$ is the degree of $f$, and the assumption is that $f$ has $m$ distinct roots in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: It is possible that $m$ is less than $\deg f$, for $f(x)$ is not necessarily squarefree. In the extremal case of $f(x)=g(x)^2$ we lose absolute irreducibility as well as the bound on $N$. With $f(x)=r(x)^2 g(x)$ the zeros of $r(x)$ lead to singularities on the curve (affecting its genus). And for the purposes of counting solutions we can then look at
$$u^2=g(x)$$
with $u=y/r(x)$ (again save for the zeros of $r(x)$), and get a better bound.